# Choosing the right format to make resulting file as small as possible [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, hex, export

I would like to understand how to choose the right format to make my resulting data file be as small as possible.

My research shows that kinda shortest values can be achieved if I use HEX format, because I can operate 256 characters (from 0 to 255), and it takes only 2 chars for example "00" or "FF". So, I think that is the shortest possible way to encode my data using my own system of parameters using HEX.

As far I understand, each character is using 7 bits, then I'm saving 1 bit with each character and it doeas mean that each 7th character can be stored so to say "free" (it will use saved bits from each 7 bytes written).

**Please correct me if I'm wrong. And if I'm totally lost with that what principals for storing data shoud I use?**

Comment: What kind of data are you storing?

Comment: what data are you trying to encode, numbers, floats, or strings?

Comment: @snakecharmerb I'm trying to create my own encoding for data. In this particular case I would like to store short names of coordinates of cells (for exemple - the first cell coordinates is 1:1, but it can be written as "00" in HEX)

Comment: also, where are you getting that a character is 7 bits and that you 'save one bit with each character'. a character can use as many bytes as needed to encode it and a byte is 8 bits.

Comment: @GeeTransit I'm styill choosing. My data vitually are coordinates. It's cells field 15X15. I would like to create my own system of coordinates that can be written to disk and shoud be as small as possible on it.

Comment: @GeeTransit as far as I understand (yet) each byte consist 8 bits. I find the info that character in HEX doesent take all 8 bits, they are using 7 bits only. So 1 bit from byte in unused.

Comment: You should probably reconsider. harddrive is cheap. Any "optimizations" you do now,you will loose as soon as you need to exchange data with other persons that then can not read it. You can store a number up to 255 in one byte - not two  chacarters if you store it binary not text.You are most probably optimizing the wrong thing - if you have huge data and then need to calculate 7 to 8 bits because you "optimized" the usage of the "unused" 8th bit ... simply dont. CPU and RAM are expensive - time as well - and you need more time if you have to decode a custom thing. I mentioned exchanging data?

Comment: you are more likely to waste more time "decoding" rather than actually working with the data.

Comment: Values from 0 to 15 can be stored in _nibbles_, i.e. two values per byte. Decoding such data is not difficult, but it does feel kind of [retro](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com) (for example: 16-color chunky graphics stores two pixel values in one byte).

Comment: @PatrickArtner I think you are right. Thank you, Patrick.

Comment: @myrmica it sounds very interesting. Should make a research in that way. Thanks!